# Alter form after submit

Tags: 7

I'm creating module to use similiar words to get better search result. I have API which will returns top X similiar words for entered word. What I want to achieve is this workflow:

1. User enter some word into the search form and submit the form
2. My module call the API, gets the similiar words and change the search query

--- That is what I have done. But next part is problem ---

3. After sucesful search, alter the form to show user the similiar words I used to change the query.

At the start I expected, that I can save similiar words in `hook_search_api_solr_query_alter` and then in `hook_form_alter` change the form to show the words. But after some research I find out that is not possible, because hooks are called in different order.

Is there any way how I can alter form after submit (or validation)?

I also tried to set `form_state['rebuild']` in validation hook, but when the form is rebuild, the entered values are erased.

Answer (score 0):

`hook_form_alter` is probably a good approach for displaying the search words in the form.

Assuming you're not submitting the form via AJAX, you need a way of passing the search words to the *next* page load. One way might be to redirect to the same URL but adding your search words as URL query parameters. You could do that by setting [$form_state['redirect']](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/drupal_redirect_form/7.x) or calling [drupal_goto](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_goto/7.x) in your *submit* function.

Another way, maybe easier, would be to save your search words in the user's [session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10490253) and reading them back in the subsequent page.